# How to move data from one table to other table?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have images in other tables with id and i want to move images from id to other table. I have comma separated ids in variable $image_url like 1,2 .I want to move images with id 1 and 2 to other table. How i can do this?

```
  $image_url = $request->input('image_id');  
  $separate_ids = explode(",", $image_url);

  foreach ($separate_ids as $ids) {

   $result_url['url'] = TempImage::where('id', '=', $separate_ids) 
      ->get(['image']);
            }
                if ($result_url) {

                    $imageModel = new Image();
                    $imageModel->user_id = $userID;
                    $imageModel->user_type = $userType;
                    $imageModel->image = $result_url;
                    $result = $imageModel->save();
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If data in json object like [{"id":1},{"id":2},{"id":3},{"id":4}]

```
$separate_ids = '[{"id":1},{"id":2},{"id":3},{"id":4}]';

$separate_ids_array = json_decode($separate_ids);

foreach($separate_ids_array as $separate_id) 
{
    // Get the URL according to the image ID
    $url = TempImage::where('id', $separate_id->id)->first()->image;

    // Store the image
    $imageModel = new Image();
    $imageModel->user_id = $userID;
    $imageModel->user_type = $userType;
    $imageModel->image = $url;
    $imageModel->save();
}
```

Comment: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given.

Comment: Copy Paste your json response here

Comment: @DaniyalMughal I have add this $separate_ids = '[{"id":1},{"id":2},{"id":3},{"id":4}]'; as staic id for your testing 
just check and let me know,

Must check your json response ids array must be in this format

 '[{"id":1},{"id":2},{"id":3},{"id":4}]'

Answer (score 0):

You need to reiterate over the separated IDs, get the details from the table they are stored at (over each ID) and insert them into the target table.

```
foreach($separate_ids as $id) 
{
    // Get the URL according to the image ID
    $url = TempImage::where('id', $id)->first()->image;

    // Store the image
    $imageModel = new Image();
    $imageModel->user_id = $userID;
    $imageModel->user_type = $userType;
    $imageModel->image = $url;
    $imageModel->save();
}
```

Comment: Ok.. If i have data in json object like [{id: 1 },{id: 2 }]. How i will explode these ids and  insert in table?

Comment: @DaniyalMughal You mentioned these are comma-separated values, not a json object. Anyhow, you will need to use json_decode($separate_ids, true);